# Cálculo dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 6 inputs e quando eu digitar um valor de porcentagem eu preciso recalcular o valor dos seguintes, mas se eu mudar algum valor de outro campo ele precisa recalcular os restantes de forma que a soma dos inputs dê 100%;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Porcentagem</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <h2 align="center">Porcentagem</h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo1" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo3" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo4" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo5" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" id="campo6" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Cálculo dinâmico de porcentaem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### O que precisas:

Saber os elementos com que trabalhas:

```
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
var destino = document.querySelector('#destino');
```

Guardar uma referência dos elementos já modificados:

```
const editados = [];
```

Ter uma função para fazer essas contas e escrever o resultado:

```
function recalcular() {
  editados.push(this);
  const restante = 100 - editados.reduce(
    (sum, el) => sum + Number(el.value || 0), 0
  );
  const total = inputs.forEach(el => {
    if (editados.includes(el)) return;
    else el.value = restante / (inputs.length - editados.length);
  });
}
```

Acionar essa função `recalcular` quando um dos inputs receber novos valores:

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', recalcular);
}
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
const destino = document.querySelector('#destino');
const editados = [];

function recalcular() {
  editados.push(this);
  const restante = 100 - editados.reduce(
    (sum, el) => sum + Number(el.value || 0), 0
  );
  const total = inputs.forEach(el => {
    if (editados.includes(el)) return;
    else el.value = restante / (inputs.length - editados.length);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', recalcular);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 align="center">Porcentagem</h2>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo1" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo3" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo4" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo5" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" id="campo6" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
<div id="destino"></div>
```